# How to freeze numbers when you have reached a certain number in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix, z:

```
z = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

for i = 2:20
    z(i,:) = z(i-1,:) + 5;
end
```

So this loop will generate a matrix starting with a line of zeros, then adding an extra 5 to each line.

I want to know how to freeze it when it reaches 30, so all values after that line will show 30's.

Therefore should look something like this:

0  0  0...

5  5  5...

10 10 10...

15 15 15...

20 20 20...

25 25 25...

30 30 30...

30 30 30...

30 30 30 etc.

Comment: Be sure not to unaccept the correct answer after a week.

Comment: Specially when it was such a neat and thorough answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `min` command to truncate the value. And use vectorization

```
>> z = repmat( min( 0:5:95, 30 )', [1 10] )
z =
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
15    15    15    15    15    15    15    15    15    15
20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20
25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25    25
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30    30
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of practice, you can add an `if` statement:

```
for i = 2:20
    z(i, :) = z(i - 1, :) + 5;
    if z(i, :) > 30
        z(i, :) = 30;
    end
end
```

... or cap it using `min`:

```
for i = 2:20
    z(i, :) = min(z(i - 1, :) + 5, 30);
end
```

However, this loop can be completely avoided if you use vectorized operations, along the lines of:

```
z = min(cumsum(5 * ones(20, 10)), 30)
```